# Show absolute positioned div on hover doesn't work

Tags: css, position, hide

I want to show a div only when mouse is hovered above him, I have this html:

```
<div class="caption">
    <h2><a href="single-image.html">Sun Flower</a></h2>
    <p class="meta-info-font">I took this photo at some bla bla bla.. and some other stuff.</p>
</div>
```

Why doesn't this work:

```
.caption {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: rgba(20,19,19,0.94);
    display: none;
}

.caption:hover {
    display: block;
}
```

UPDATE: if I use opacity it doesn't hide the children elements - the `h2` and `p`. how do I hide all of them with only CSS?

Answer (score 4):

If it's not displayed, you can't hover it. You should instead use its [opacity property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/jj127325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2nEVW/

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned,you can use Opacity for div tag, like this :
http://jsfiddle.net/xGQ26/2/